# SimpleChildWindows binded to View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, mahapps.metro

I'm using MVVM Light, MahApps and SimpleChildWindows.

I want to be able to create a CRUD Form in a modal popup.

This CRUD form must be binded to its own ViewModel and called by a command in another ViewModel.

I don't succeed to do this with SimpleChildWindows...

So... Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sometimes the solution is under my nose but I struggle to see it...

So here is my solution:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid >
        <UserControl Content="{Binding Path=CurrentViewModel}"/>
    </Grid>
    <simpleChildWindow:ChildWindow IsOpen="{Binding OpenChildWindows}"
                                   Title="{Binding TitleChildWindows}"
                                   Content="{Binding CurrentWindowsViewModel }"/>
</Grid>
```

The CurrentWindowsViewModel is binded to a UserControl which fits perfectly in the Content property of my SimpleChildWindows.

However I must Bind all the ChildWindows properties to the Viewmodel which "Host" my childwindows ("Title", "IsOpen" etc).

All the ChildWindows ViewModel inherit from a class Template (which obviously inherits from ViewModelBase) with a Title and maybe some others properties specific to ChildWindows.

I communicate through the MVVM light Messenger to tell the  "Host" which ViewModel to display by its name and then I read its"Title" and open the Windows by the "IsOpen" propertie:

```
        private void ReceiveMessage(EnumViewModelNames viewName)
        {
        var selectedViewModel = ViewModelList.Where(x => x.ViewModelName == viewName).SingleOrDefault();
        if (selectedViewModel is TemplateWindowsViewModel)
        {
            TitleChildWindows = (selectedViewModel as TemplateWindowsViewModel).Title;
            OpenChildWindows = true;
            CurrentWindowsViewModel = (selectedViewModel as TemplateWindowsViewModel);
        }
        else if (selectedViewModel != null)
        {
            CurrentViewModel = selectedViewModel;
        }
        Messenger.Default.Unregister<EnumViewModelNames>(this, (action) => ReceiveMessage(action));
        }
```

This way, I'm able to open the childWindows from the "CurrentViewModel", or the "MainViewModel".

It works pretty well and the view is simply a standard Usercontrol binded to a DataContext in the ViewModelLocator.

Sorry Heorhiy Pavlovych, I've seen that you were trying hard, but we misunderstood...

Comment: Hello Speuline, This post is old, but for me it´s new :) , I have the same problem, but I can´t succeed to make it working. Can you please provide me an example of your example working. Best regards. Jolynice

Comment: Hello, do you use SimpleChildWindows library?

Comment: Hello Speuline, Yes I use SimpleChildWindows Library. I am novice with WPF :( , can you help me, please. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what I can add... You just have to add the namespace of SimpleChildWindows to the usercontrol which will host you childWindows, then you do what I wrote in this answer: bind directly the "open" property to your viewModel. And when you want to open the windows, you just  pass the IsOpen property to true (don't forget the raisepropertyChange or INotifyPropertyChanged). Also, don't forget to assign the CurrentWindowsViewModel property to the viewModel of your childWindows. Send me some code if you're in trouble, and I'll see what can I do.

Comment: Hi Speuline, I will try again, with your advice. I will give you my feedback. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How I solved similar problem for myself, taking advantage of Dependency Injection:

I used [Unity](https://unity.codeplex.com/) and registered dependency to 'Func':

```
public partial class App
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<EntityCRUDWindowViewModel>();
        container.RegisterType<ConsumerViewModel>();
        container.RegisterInstance<Func<Entity, EntityCRUDWindow>>(entity =>  new EntityCRUDWindow(){DataContext=container.Resolve<EntityCRUDWindowViewModel>(new ParameterOverride("entity", new InjectionParameter<Entity>(entity))));
        /* whatever goes here */
    }
}
```

ViewModel for the CRUD window looks like

```
public class EntityCRUDWindowViewModel
{
    private readonly Entity entity;

    public EntityCRUDWindowViewModel(Entity entity)
    {
        this.entity = entity;
    }
}
```

and you can get the instance of window `EntityCRUDWindow` and use it in `ConsumerViewModel` or any other ViewModel by simply declaring in constructor parameter

```
public class ConsumerViewModel
{
    public ConsumerViewModel(Func<Entity, EntityCRUDWindow> entityCrudWindowFactory)
    {
       this.WhateverCommand = new DelegateCommand(
           () =>
           {
               Entity someEntity = null; //or whatever
               entityCrudWindowFactory(someEntity).ShowDialog();
           });
    }

    public ICommand WhateverCommand { get; }
}
```

Thus, you can put any dependency you need in constructor parameters of both viewmodels, just keeping in mind that `Entity entity` parameter must be present in `EntityCRUDWindowViewModel`.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see how it'll helps me... I want to have a modal CRUD dialog. Your code allows me to create a CRUD ViewModel.

Comment: It is a way to make window accessible from anywhere. My code does not create viewmodel, it creates view (window in this case) by itself

Comment: I think I've badly explains what I wanted, maybe my "edit" will explains better.

Comment: I see. Yeah, that is another story.sorry ;)  do you have a list of crudviewmodel in your main VM?

Comment: I've a list of ViewModel in my main VM and they communicate through messages (MVVM Light Messenger)

Comment: It depends how many windows you need. If only one you might want to set ActiveWindow. If all of them need to be edited at the same time try ItemsControl

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add DataTemplate to resources and that will render whenever you bind Content to some CrudViewModelType instance

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type whateverNs:MyCrudViewModelType}">
                <UserControl Content="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ContentControl Content={Binding CurrentCrudViewModel}></ContentControl>
        <simpleChildWindow:ChildWindow IsOpen="{Binding OpenChildWindows}" Content="{Binding MyCrudViewModel}"/>
    </Grid>
```