# MVVM Dialogs and where to call them from?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, modal-dialog

Hoping that someone can help me further my understanding of Dialogs and how to apply them to the App I am working on (for learning purposes). Apologies in advance - I do not have a great working knowledge of a lot of these different technologies

The basic layout of my viewmodel structure is as in the Pic below (with corresponding Views(UserControls)
[ViewModel Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wijlm.png)

In the `GroupView` Model each tab is set to a Food Group for the Restaurant and the items loaded at runtime

```
 <ItemsControl Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Plus}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="410" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Margin="5" Width="80" Height="40"
                                Command="{Binding DataContext.AddPluCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=core:UserControlViewBase}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PluContent}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

On the `Button click` (via the Command : AddPluCommand) I would Like to `trigger` a Prep Instruction Dialog (or modal View)

**Example:**

On Pressing Coffee - Prep Instructions would load view with 3 buttons:

- Hot Milk
- Cold Milk
- Black

All Attempts so far have yielded no results (Interaction Triggers, Dialog Service, Overlay Modal Views). The most likely reason is that I am placing the code in the wrong `ViewModels` (at least I think that's the reason).

**Questions:**

Is it possible to load a Dialog with its own `ViewModel` (as described above). Only Samples I have seen deal with very simple text type messages?

Which `Viewmodel` should be Calling the Dialog?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found very difficult to build modal Dialog with WPF.
Now I use the Mahapps Metro SimpleChildWindows, you can download it with Nugets.

This way you can build a custom modal view with its own ViewModel (if you want).
Look at my question (and my answer) 
=> [SimpleChildWindows binded to View Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41617475/simplechildwindows-binded-to-view-model)

Comment: Thanks @Speuline - Looking into that now